# ORA-7445 Error on 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I am installing an Oracle 12.1.0.1 Enterprise Edition on RHEL 6.4
I set it up with ASMM and HugePages  (64G of RAM)

There may be a correlation between the errors and signing in to em express (not 100% certain yet).  I mention this because of the following blog post with a similar error: http://surachartopun.com/2013/06/learn-something-wtih-12c-and-enjoy-bug.html

I have opened an SR already but wanted to see if anyone had thoughts on this.

```
Fri Aug 30 14:53:22 2013
Exception [type: SIGSEGV, Address not mapped to object] [ADDR:0x5] [PC:0xB71F161, qervwRowProcedure()+113] [flags: 0x0, count: 1]
Errors in file /home/oracle/diag/rdbms/prdtdr1m/prdtdr1m/trace/prdtdr1m_s000_5987.trc  (incident=33811):
ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [qervwRowProcedure()+113] [SIGSEGV] [ADDR:0x5] [PC:0xB71F161] [Address not mapped to object] []
Incident details in: /home/oracle/diag/rdbms/prdtdr1m/prdtdr1m/incident/incdir_33811/prdtdr1m_s000_5987_i33811.trc
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Fri Aug 30 14:53:24 2013
Dumping diagnostic data in directory=[cdmp_20130830145324], requested by (instance=1, osid=5987 (S000)), summary=[incident=33811].
Fri Aug 30 14:53:33 2013
Sweep [inc][33811]: completed
Sweep [inc2][33811]: completed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle Support instructed me to apply patch: 16527374